# Looking for Equivalent Transistor

Tags: transistors

Here is Fm Transmitter Circuits The Transistor  **2N3563** used here is not easily available in my city. What characteristics should I look for in a replacement?
[image]

Comment: 2N3563 appears to be commonly used as a "NPN RF amplifier". I'd suggest you dig up the datasheet for it and then head over to the parametric search at a large electronics distributor (digikey is usually my 1st try) and look for something similar with the relevant specs. The numbers in the 'small-signal characteristics' section will probably be most significant. Unfortunately only you know what parts are actually available where you live...

Comment: https://octopart.com/search?q=2N3563

Comment: I saw ft listed at 600 MHz... would a nice surface mount part work for you?  (Digikey had one through hole at 500 MHz.  2N2369.. a metal can even :^)

Answer (score 2):

Look for something (an NPN transistor- might be called an RF transistor-, of course) with similar (or *somewhat* higher) ft, similar or somewhat lower Cob, and hfe in the same range (to make it more likely it oscillates), and similar (or somewhat higher) Pd, Vceo, and Ic (to make sure it doesn't burn out).

Package is up to you whether you want to try to duplicate it or not - that one (TO-106) is probably obsolete so it will be hard to duplicate exactly. A TO-92 may be better (like a PN3563). Eg. 2N5770, and there are some 2SC numbers too, but as you don't disclose the city/country it's hard to guess whether Japanese, European or US part numbers would likely be more available.

There are a few (Japanese, mostly) TO-92 transistors that have an ft in the 4-7GHz or higher range- I would *not* suggest using one of those (ft can be too high as well as too low).